# How to get the Windows 7 bootloader back after installing XP, as well?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

So I installed XP on a partition alongside Windows 7 and I have lost the Windows 7 bootloader.  I'd like to have it back, even if it means getting rid of XP, as I no longer need it.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you no longer need XP why don't you delete it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer need Windows XP, I would personally just do a fresh install and format as you will get rid of a lot of the "relics" that are no longer needed.

Otherwise, the easiest way to simply reinstate the Windows 7 Bootloader is to put in any Windows 7 DVD and on the first screen, choose the `Repair` option and then it should automatically scan for problems.

If it does not find it automatically, choose `Start up repair` and it should copy and reinstall the bootloader.

[image]

(Top Option)

Comment: a fresh install and format on the whole harddrive?  i would like to keep my windows 7 partition.  and possibly regrow it, if possible

Comment: I agree and my second answer will mean you do not have to... I am just saying that in the first, it will remove all the junk and old items left over by Windows XP that you no longer need... but I agree, it is overkill if you are already using your Windows 7 a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the DVD. on the second screen (after you choose your language) go to **repair your computer**. then go to **command prompt** and type this:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Press enter.

Then type this:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

Press enter.

Restart.

Comment: @ Molly7244 : Thanks a billion for your answer. I had the same problem and I got my bootloader back with these simple commands.