# Fresh install Windows 7 bootloader with Command-Line tools only

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the Windows 7 bootloader back after installing XP, as well?](https://superuser.com/questions/87864/how-to-get-the-windows-7-bootloader-back-after-installing-xp-as-well)

How can I freshly reinstall the bootloader? Using the tools `bcdedit.exe`, `bootrec.exe`, and/or `bootsect.exe` that come with Windows 7.

Assume that the bootloader is in an undefied state, it could be working or completely missing.

Comment: Possible duplicates [How do I install the Windows 7 boot loader?](http://superuser.com/questions/234824/how-do-i-install-the-windows-7-boot-loader) and [How to get the Windows 7 bootloader back after installing XP, as well?](http://superuser.com/questions/87864/how-to-get-the-windows-7-bootloader-back-after-installing-xp-as-well)

Answer (score 2):

To write a new boot sector on your system, try

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

But if it is damaged, you can use `fixmbr` to restore it

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Enter `bootrec /?` to see all the available options.

But for these commands to work, you might need to use the recovery command prompt booting from the Windows disc, then select `Repair Your Computer`, and from recovery options, choose `Command Prompt`.